Can I create Record-triggered flow for SObject?
Pretty much as title says: Can we create a flow for SObject? making it universal...
I can give an example of use-case:

Update Contact's salutation based on gender;

Update Lead's salutation based on gender;


Now I can create a trigger with apex class and make it generic with SObject, meaning I can have one method for both Contact and Lead.
Can I do the same in Flow?

You can't create a record-triggered flow for SObject. You need to select the specific object when you create a record trigger flow.

You can create an Autolaunched Flow, which can then be triggered by Record-Triggered Flows on the Contact and Lead objects. This is the equivalent of using an Apex Class and calling it from two different triggers.
